# how to override a method from an inherited class

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I use core-plot and I have to override a method in CPTLayer for CPTAxisLabel, but not for all labels, so I made an CustomCPTAxisLabel class to do that. 
The problem is that I have to override renderAsVectorInContext witch is a method from CPTLayer, 
CPTAxisLabel inherits CPTLayer and CustomCPTAxisLabel inherits CPTAxisLabel (something like this : CPTLayer->CPTAxisLabel->CustomCPTAxisLabel). The question is how can I override a method from CPTLayer in CustomCPTAxisLabel ?

Answer (score 0):

In Your subclass *CustomCPTAxisLabel*, define the method, which you want to override *renderAsVectorInContext*. Something like

> -(void)renderAsVectorInContext:(CGContextRef)context {
>
> ```
>  [super renderAsVectorInContext:context];
>
>  // Do customisation after this.
> ```
>
> }

You may or may not choose to override this method in *CPTAxisLabel* class, but if you do make a call to super class.

Comment: I all ready tried that, but the method just doesn't get called, and I can`t figure why...

Comment: Can you post some code from _CustomCPTAxisLabel_ class. Also the code from where you are allocating the object for it.

Comment: in .h I have   #import "CPTAxisLabel.h"

interface CustomCPTAxisLabel : CPTAxisLabel


-(void)renderAsVectorInContext:(CGContextRef)context;

end      and in .m @implementation CustomCPTAxisLabel

-(void)renderAsVectorInContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    [super renderAsVectorInContext:context];
    
}

Comment: also if I (command + click)on the method in CustomCptAxisLabel.m leads me to CPTLayer.h, but on run time break point in custom class method doesn`t get hit...

Comment: Are you sure that _CPTAxisLabel_ is inheriting from _CPTLayer_ class? I just checked in an old code of mine and it is not so, it is inheriting from _NSObject_. The method, which you are trying to override is present in _CPTLayer_ but concept of inheritance won't be applicable to your _CustomCPTAxisLabel_ class.

Comment: I know that default it inherits NSObject, but I changed it so it inherits CPTLayer